# Tar directory and file structure without the file data

Tags: bash, tar, bash-scripting

Is it possible to create a tar with the folder and file name structure, but without any of the file data?

So a reference tar ball effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one may have both directories and (sym-)links in a *tar* file: see [Tar Format Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html).

In this case, one would have an archived structure, but no file content in the *tar* archive.